# Как правильно завершить метод если он работает более определенного времени

Tags: android

Добрый день.
Есть задача чтоб определенный метод выполнялся не более X секунд. и если выполняется больше бросается какое либо исключение, а метод завершается. Проблема в том что функция делает запрос через сокет, и он может быть бесконечным в случае проблем на удаленной стороне.
Пока в мыслях запускать 2 потока в одном выполнять сам метод, а в другом считать время, и если время превышено, то убивать первый метод.
Но возможно есть готовое решение? Например через анатации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй таймер, ему можно указать время жизни. Тем самым, когда истечет время, он умрет и убьет все что насоздавал. Останется отловить исключения.